# Force the Xbox Music app to search for MP3s on drives other than C:

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store-app, xbox-music

I have a new computer with Windows 8.1 and the Xbox Music app.

When I put my music in `C:\Users\[username]\My Music`, Xbox Music finds it. However, the app doesn't search my `D:` drive. How do I make it search on the `D:` drive or on other volumes?

Answer (score 1):

To add music files from other folders to your Xbox Music collection, simply add that folder to your Music library:

1. Open Windows Explorer (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) and navigate to the folder in question.
2. Right-click on the folder and select "Include in library" → "Music".
3. Done!

This can also be done from within the Xbox Music app itself:

1. While in the Xbox Music app, open the Charms bar (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and click on Settings.
2. Go to Preferences, then click on "Choose where we look for music on this PC".
3. In the new dialog that pops up, click on the **+** button, which brings up a Metro-style folder chooser.
4. Find the folder where your MP3 files are stored, then click on "Add this folder to Music".
5. Done!